# What are all the possible direct interactions between bosons in Standard Model?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, bosons

For the bosons $g$, $\gamma$, $Z$, $W$, $H$ in the standard model, what are all of the possible direct interactions between them?

Some of the interactions I can think of are $H \rightarrow ZZ$, $HH \rightarrow WW$, $HH \rightarrow ZZ$ and $g \rightarrow gg$.

Comment: For that you would need to consider all the interaction terms in the standard model Lagrangian which involve the bosonic fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the gauge and Higgs kinetic & potential  terms of the EW model and read off the vertices: The fun should be the actual strengths of the couplings, which I should not spoil by revealing it to you. (To check your work, go to Appendix B of Li & Cheng).

- Gluons only couple to themselves, among the bosons, so you have cubic and quartic terms for them--renormalizability will allow for nothing else.

So, in the remainder EW sector, you have

- Cubics: γWW; ZWW; HWW; HZZ; HHH;
- Quartics: γγWW; WWZZ; HHHH; ZZZZ; HHZZ; HHWW; WWWW; ZHWW; γHWW; γZWW .

Reassure yourself you appreciate which terms each comes from. If it looked haphazard, it is only because I skipped the coupling strengths, which reveal the method in the model's madness.

The most interesting ones, in my view, come from the covariant completions of the Higgs doublet "kinetic" terms.

- *Extra credit:* Can you intuit why there are no  γγZ,  γZZ (duh!), ZZZ,  ZHH and ZHHH terms?